# Sharing Bootstrap across WordPress projects

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm working on several WordPress projects that all use the same template and core WordPress files. So I split the folders like so:

```
wordpress-
  -wp-content
   -themes
    -mytheme
     -output
      -core.css
     -src
      -bootstrap
       -files.scss
     -sass
      -core.scss

project
  -outputs
   -project.css
  -sass
   -project.scss
```

both my project.scss and core.scss use @extend and @include using bootstrap sass files.

I can indeed @import bootstrap at the top of project.scss as well as core.scss, but then I will end up with duplicate of bootstrap.

Is there a way to avoid it? how would you approach it? I feel that importing just the bootstrap files I need for the project is still a waste. There must be a way for sass to go into the files, extract what final css it needs from bootstrap for @extend/@include and leave the rest out of the final project.css

I hope I'm explaining this right.

Comment: Module dependency issues like this can be solved by using proper build tools. If I was trying to achieve something similar to this, personally i'd use webpack (this theme is a great starter with webpack in it - https://roots.io/sage/).

If you don't want to jump into new techmlogieis, i'd just say you need to architect your scss better. Have one main file which includes vendor dependencies

Comment: I'm already using gulp. It all boils down to this: I have two main css files, project and core. Both are generated by two main scss files that each imports other files which in turn use extend and include to borrow Bootstrap's classes. It seems like a terrible waste to load ALL of bootstrap or even ALL of the needed partial just to, for instance, @extend a col... A more logical solution: get there, get the needed class, copy to final css.